# SQL Return 0 subscribers who opened newsletter 1 and 2

Tags: sql

```
id  subscriberid newsletterid Opened
1       1         1              yes
2       1         2              yes
3       2         1              yes
```

My SQL Query should be something like :

```
select subscriberid
from email_marketing 
where Opened=1 and (newsletterid=1 and newsletterid=2);
```

But it returns empty record. I am trying to display all subscribers who opened newsletterid 1 & 2.

The expected outcome is subscriberid 1, who opened both newsletters (id 1 & 2). 
Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

For a single record `newsletterid` cannot be 2 different values at the same time. So you need to build a group and look at the complete group.

```
select subscriberid
from email_marketing 
where Opened = 1 and newsletterid in (1,2)
group by subscriberid
having count(distinct newsletterid) = 2
```

You need to group by the `subscriberid` and then you can count the different `newsletterid` that you previously filtered and these should be two.